# How to Stream H265 Multicast Video Using Gstreamer?

Tags: encoding, gstreamer, h.264, h.265, petalinux

I have a script that stream video on petalinux as multicast with H.264, but when I changed settings for H.265, I think I still encode with H.264 (wireshark protocol says H.264).

Here is my sender script

`gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=4 ! queue ! vtracking ! queue ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! v4l2video1convert capture-io-mode=4 output-io-mode=5 ! video/x-raw,format=NV16,width=$3,height=$4, framerate=30/1 ! omxh265enc num-slices=16 periodicity-idr=240 cpb-size=500 gdr-mode=horizontal initial-delay=250 control-rate=low-latency prefetch-buffer=true target-bitrate=$2 gop-mode=low-delay-p ! video/x-h265, alignment=nal ! h265parse ! rtph265pay ! udpsink buffer-size=2000000000 host=224.1.1.1 port=$1 auto-multicast=true async=false max-lateness=-1 qos-dscp=60 max-bitrate=120000000 -v`

Actually this script was for H.264. When it was H.264, all 265's were 264. I also changed the VCU IP from FPGA side for H 265.

Where is my fault?

Thanks,
M.Altay

Comment: Is there any comment? Problem is still open.

Answer (score 1):

[Petalinux omxh265enc](https://xilinx.gitlab.avnet.com/petalinux/gstreamer-reference/v2019.1/elements/video/omxh265enc/) seems not to have `alignment=nal` property as [Petalinux omxh264enc](https://xilinx.gitlab.avnet.com/petalinux/gstreamer-reference/v2019.1/elements/video/omxh264enc/) does. Try fixing the encoder upstream caps like this:

```
video/x-h265,stream-format=byte-stream,alignment=au
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your reply. Acutally it does not give an error on alingment=nal, It streams the video. My problem is every setting is for H265, but in wireshark it still seen as H264 encoding.